# Android App that has an element which is sticked to bottom on every page

Tags: android, xml

i want to create an android app that has a music play at the bottom of the app. We gonna switch between activites but i want that music player to keep playing. How should i achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a particular view at every activity/fragment?  Create a separate layout with your desired view and include it in xml file of activities/fragments.

example :

```
 <include layout="@layout/your_layout"></include>
```

Comment: Let say i audio was playing an it was at 3.00m and suddenly the layout is changed then what would be the effect on audio either it will keep playing onwards from 3.00m or it will start from beginnig

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fragment` instead of many activities or use Viewpager. If you are not friends with those you can also create base activity with music player and extend other activities from it. But best way to do such thing is using fragments and Viewpager makes it even more easier.

Read [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments)  article to get familiar with fragment